# image carousel with each image having its own clickable gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to make a image carousel that would have an clickable image gallery on each photo. Images go in a carousel, and if I click one, it opens a gallery of images that are its own ( are different). Tried modals, but couldn't get them working. Many different carousels, slideshows, but couldn't find out what to do

Comment: if you show me code i can help you out

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PErxox this is what I have

Comment: use model then change model image by src sibling img tag this is simple algorithm

Comment: I'm quite new to this, could you explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create  a carousel and modal

below script changes img in model with arrow mprev (previous) & mnext(next)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.modal ').hide();


 $('.carousel > img').click(function(){
  var im=$(this).attr('src');
 $('.modal').css('display','block');
 $('.modal > img').attr('src',im);

   });
 $('.mprev').click(function(){
    var i= $('.modal > img').attr('src');
    var p= $('img[src='+i+']');
    var im=p.parent().previous().child('img');
    im=im.attr('src');
    $('.modal > img').attr('src',im);
 });
 $('.mnext').click(function(){
    var i= $('.modal > img').attr('src');
    var p= $('img[src='+i+']');
    var im=p.parent().next().child('img');
    im=im.attr('src');
    $('.modal > img').attr('src',im);
 });
});
```

note : i am not familiar with bootstrap so use new class mentioned above or replace selectors with bootstrap class

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at something i made recently [here](https://github.com/brickers/galleroid). It is not a carousel but does show a two-level gallery where you see a list of projects, and then further detail within each project.

Essentially there is a list of elements which make up the contents of the first carousel, and then nested within that are a number of other image and paragraph elements. when you click on one of the initial items, it expands, there are scroll buttons revealed and images and paragraphs of text are scrolled through using jquery to add a 'visible' class to them, and CSS animations to add/remove them from view